# Getting Kit Info in Qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

I am using two kits in a project. Kits have different version of c++ compilers of course.
I want to enter specific block in the profile according to chosen kit for building. For example:

```
i_selected_first_kit{
DEFINES += VAL
}
i_selected_second_kit{
DEFINES -= VAL
}
```

How can I do it?